# Sharepoint 2013 external lists: ListItem.Update() is reverting item values

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I've an external list with an item which has a field called "CostPerUnit". This field has a value already setted and I'm trying to change its value with the following code:

```
private void updateCost(int orderIndex, decimal cost)
{
    SPContext.Current.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    SPListItem item = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[CListNames.ORDERS].Items[orderIndex];

    item["CostPerUnit"] = cost;

    item.Update();

    SPContext.Current.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
```

When I call "item.Update()", it happens that before calling my Updater method Sharepoint is calling the ReadItem (the Specific Finder), which is overriding the entire list item with the original values from Database. Here are my Specific Finder and Updater methods:

```
public static TB_ORDER ReadItem(int id, decimal costPerUnit, string comments)
{
    OT_MODEL_DALDataContext dataContext = new OT_MODEL_DALDataContext(_ConnectionString);
    TB_ORDER Order = (from order in dataContext.TB_ORDERs.AsEnumerable() where order.Id == id select order).Single();
    return Order;
}

public static void Update(TB_ORDER order)
{
    OT_MODEL_DALDataContext dataContext = new OT_MODEL_DALDataContext(_ConnectionString);

    var Order = (from orders in dataContext.TB_ORDERs
                      where orders.Id == order.Id
                      select orders).Single();

    Order.Comments= order.Comments;
    Order.CostPerUnit = order.CostPerUnit;

    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The 'order' item passed to the updater method is the one retrieved by the specific finder method, so the changes done to the item are lost and not commited to de Database.

*Update*My question is: How can I prevent Sharepoint from overriding the ItemList with its original values before it calls the updater method?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: How do I prevent Sharepoint from overriding the ListItem with its original values?

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote some code for my project that updates a SharePoint list item field and it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https:///jquery.SPServices-2013.02a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadConstants, "sp.js"); });        

function loadConstants() {

    //get item id from url
    var docurl = document.URL;
    var beginindex = docurl.indexOf('?ID=') + 4;
    var endindex = docurl.indexOf('&Source=');
    var itemid = docurl.substring(beginindex, endindex);

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext("your site url");
        var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('your list name');
        this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemid);

        ctx.load(this.oListItem);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {  
            this.oListItem.set_item('Column name', "New value");
            this.oListItem.update();

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
                          Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
                    }),  function (sender, args) { alert('Error occured' + args.get_message());});    

    }
    function onError(error) {
        alert("error");
    }       
}    
</script>
```

I hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks Ekaterina, I'll check it as soon as I go back to the office. Just to be sure: the list you are updating is an external list, right?

Comment: I used this code for a list on my site, but I think it should work for an external list when you specify: SP.ClientContext("your site url");    and   ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('your list name'); I'm not 100% sure, but it worth trying ;)

Comment: Hello, I finally have tried with your code and i'm getting exactly the same behaviour. The item is returned to its original values just before it's being updated on the Database. Thanks anyway!